# A sufficient condition for a finite group to have a $p$-power order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime number. If $G$ is a $p$-group, i.e. the order of every element of $G$ is a power of $p$ then is the order of $G$ equal to some power of $p$?  How do I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), if there is another $q$ dividing $|G|$, then there exist an element of order $q$ in $G$ for prime $q$ which conclude the result.

Comment: stackexchange eats apostrophes like in the link to Cauchy's theorem. I fixed it with the %27

Comment: ... but it does URL encoding automatically if the link is inserted via Ctrl-L (the "link" button in the editor). @JackSchmidt

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY: awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $|G|$ has another prime-power factor $q^k$ ($k$ maximal), by the first Sylow's theorem, it has a subgroup whose order is precisely $q^k$. Then, if every subgroup has an order $p^j$, the order of $G$ can not have divisors that are not powers of $p$.